# Home button image size

Tags: android, user-interface

It seems that my home button image size gets its dimension from the original image, how can make it smaller so it just fits in my actionbar?

**Note**: I can't resize the image since that image is for hdpi screen.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.Transparent.EstablishmentProfile" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/edit</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding the resource for other folders also such as hdpi, mdpi. This may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but if you want a large image to fit into the Action Bar, I'd recommend using https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html to re-size it, and then load that into your respective drawable folders.